# Array is not working well

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am new in PHP. I have a code in which i use 2 sql commands. First command fetch 1st latest row and second command fetch 2nd latest row. This code is place in file `sqlquery.php`

here is code of `sqlquery.php`

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
```

**Problem of my code is my array print same record in all rows. But in Db there is different records. My code is print only first record in each row**

I want to output of my code is like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the double loop, now for every result from the first query you add an array item for each result of the second query duplicating the array items effectively, you can change this

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
```

To:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
```

It would be better to change your sql query though to incorporate all values in one request.

Another thing you can do, though is less nice:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{        
    $opinion[]= $row1['opinion'];
    $action[]= $row1['atitle'];
    $long_term[]= $row1['ltitle'];
    $outlook[]= $row1['otitle'];
    $rating_type[]= $row1['ttitle'];
    $short_term[]= $row1['stitle'];
}
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $p_long_term[]= $row2['ltitle'];
    $p_short_term[]= $row2['stitle'];
}
```

Comment: Did you also remove one of the closing brackets (`}`)? Turn on errors with `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1); `